# I want to replace the value of an object inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, replace, array.prototype.map

I have a timestamp in my array that I have removed the UTC letters from and I want to replace the old timestamp with the "new" timestamp(without UTC)
Maybe there is an even easier way to do the removing?

So I've tried to loop over my data with .forEach and .map trying to replace it but still haven't figure it out how to exactly do so.
I've watched a bunch of Stackoverflow threads about this but haven't found a solution that I get to work....clearly missing something or writing something wrong.

So can anyone guide me how to solve this in the best way?

```
const data = [
  {
    timestamp: "2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC",
    url: "/blub.html",
    userid: "12345"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC",
    url: "/cont.html ",
    userid: "12346"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC ",
    url: "/cont.html ",
    userid: "12345"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC",
    url: "/ho.html ",
    userid: "12347"
  }
];

console.log("data", data);
console.log("ex: first data object:", data[0]);


//loop through and grab the timestamp in each object and remove the UTC stamp
const GrabTimeStamp = () => {
  data.forEach(function (objects, index) {
   
    const timeStamp = objects.timestamp;
    const newTimeStamp = timeStamp.slice(0, 19);
    console.log("newTimeStamp:", newTimeStamp, index);

//next step to replace the old timestamp with newTimeStamp

  });
};
GrabTimeStamp()
```

Comment: Hey your idea looks good. Do you know about splice? Also maybe you can do the slicing when you ask for the timestamp the first time, save some of the trouble of looping again. Lastly don't forget to return in the end of the function.

Comment: Thank you @billybadass, yes did try .splice first but didn't get that to work either, a lot of practice left to do. Thanks for input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, just refactor that fragment (best approach to work with `forEach`):

```
data.forEach((item, index) => {
   const timeStamp = item.timestamp;
   const newTimeStamp = timeStamp.slice(0, 19);
   item.timestamp = newTimeStamp; 
});
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @Sa1m0n it works....was trying the .foreach again under the first one, but realise that I should have just continued, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that variables declared with "const" could not be changed? So it seems like you want to use "var" here. The last 3 letters can be removed by "slice(0, -3)".

```
var data = [
  {
    timestamp: "2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC",
    url: "/blub.html",
    userid: "12345"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2019-03-01 09:00:00UTC",
    url: "/cont.html ",
    userid: "12346"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2019-03-01 10:00:00UTC",
    url: "/cont.html ",
    userid: "12345"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2019-03-01 10:30:00UTC",
    url: "/ho.html ",
    userid: "12347"
  }
];

console.log("data", data);
console.log("ex: first data object:", data[0]);


//loop through and grab the timestamp in each object and remove the UTC stamp
var grabTimeStamp = () => {
  data.forEach(function (object, index) {
   
    var newTimeStamp = object.timestamp.slice(0, -3);
    console.log("newTimeStamp:", newTimeStamp, index);

    //next step to replace the old timestamp with newTimeStamp
    object.timestamp = newTimeStamp;
  });
};
grabTimeStamp();
```

Since it does seem like you are fairly new to coding, I tried to change only a few things in your code. However your function grabTimeStamp can be done shorter:

```
function removeTimestamp(data){
    data.foreach((item, index) => {
        item.timestamp = item.timestamp.slice(0, -3);
    });
}
removeTimestamp(data);
```

Comment: Objects and arrays declared with `const` could be changed. Only primitive data types like strings or numbers couldn't.

Comment: while it is possible because of how js works, it defeats the purpose declaring them "const". Overall when learning how to code using "var" will probably result in less errors

Comment: Thanks! Yes new to coding trying to get my head around JS, nice and neat code, thanks!

Comment: I disagree; `let` and `const` are block-scoped and within its scope `newTimeStamp` never changes therefore it is perfectly licit (and I'd say preferable) to declare it with `const`.